# Istio + Helm + Tiller Instalation - How to secure everything?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio

I have K8s installed in a 3 nodes cluster. I want to install Istio in a secure way. My question is: When installing Istio via Helm (as recommended in the [docs](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/helm-install/#option-1-install-with-helm-via-helm-template)) do I need to install Helm securely (RABC and TSL/SSL) as recommended in the [Docs](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#installing-helm)?

The reason for this question is the conflicting information between the two documentations. The Istio docs say only to do a simple `helm init --service-account tiller`. However in the Helm documentations it is recommended to go through all the security of Helm. In other words: Does Istio covers Helm insecure installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/helm-install/#option-1-install-with-helm-via-helm-template) about deploying Istio via Helm chart, the implementation steps won’t cover any security configuration to your `Tiller` service by default. Therefore, if you consider using a cluster with no concerns to the development environment the best solution would be applying [Security configuration](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#securing-your-helm-installation) to Helm chart.

In general, Istio security implementation covers three concepts: [Authentication policies](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authentication-policies), [Mutual TLS authentication](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#mutual-tls-authentication) and [Authorization policy](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization-policy).

Basically, Istio mesh installation via Helm chart enables Mutual TLS authentication by default with the existing parameter `global.mtls.enabled` in Helm template.

Comment: Are you saying that it is best to apply both security protocols? Is that is?

Comment: I guess the best practice for non development projects would be applying security configuration either for Helm chart and Istio mesh services.